# Magento 2 Content Pages and Blocks not loading grid

Tags: magento2

I am seeing the following when loading the Content > Pages or Content > Blocks section of a magento 2.0.0 site.

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

[image: The Grid for Content > Pages never loads]

Comment: My Magento 2 pages and blocks won't load in the Admin/ Backend in any browser. I have tried it in FireFox, Chrome and IE and the pages and blocks are not loading in any of them. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an issue with the javascript library. In chrome it causes an exception to be thrown on the page, preventing the grids from loading.

The page works correctly on Firefox - and this issue is only present on Chrome.  A git issue has been recorded on git.hub, and can be followed here:

[Issue as it stands on github.com](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3601)

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while to load the pages grid on chrome

Comment: I did wait for several minutes even 10-15 minutes - and I also verified that on the server I was on (dev server) no active apache2 processes were running.  That coupled with the fact that it works within seconds on firefox - leads me to believe that there is a browser specific issue.

Comment: Can you clear the magento cache and reload the page on firefox and see if the page load properly?

Comment: It definitely is broken on chrome and works on Firefox.  I posted that as a solution last night, but it was removed